# Creating a list of my favorites

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

The C++ application I am creating allows a user to add or remove their favorite games to a list.

I want the list to be ordered.

1. Legend Of Zelda
2. Contra
3. GTA V

I know I will need to use a while/ for loop, however I am using vector(s) which I am a newbie, and I don't know where to place the while/ for loop in my code.

What I have tried so far is:

Failed attempt 1 - A nested for loop:

```
 for (gameInter = list.begin(); gameInter != list.end(); gameInter++) {
       for (int listNum = 1; listNum < list.size(); listNum++) {
            cout << listNum << ". " << *gameInter << endl;
        }
    }
```

Failed Attempt 2 - A while loop:

```
case 1:
         while(listNum < list.size()) {
            cout << "Type the game title to add: \n";
            cin.get();
            getline(cin, addGame);
                list.push_back(addGame);
                sort(list.begin(), list.end());
                cin.clear();
                cin.sync();
                cout << "\nYour game was successfully added.\n";
                listNum++;
         }
            break;
```

Complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int userSelection = 0;
    int listNum = 1;

    string addGame, removeGame;

    vector<string> list;
    vector<string>::iterator gameInter;

    while (userSelection != 4) {

        cout << "Type 1 to add a game to your list\n";
        cout << "Type 2 to remove a game from your list\n";
        cout << "Type 3 to list all games\n";
        cout << "Type 4 to quit\n";

        cin >> userSelection;

        switch (userSelection) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Type the game title to add: \n";
            cin.get();
            getline(cin, addGame);
                list.push_back(addGame);
                sort(list.begin(), list.end());
                cin.clear();
                cin.sync();
                cout << "\nYour game was successfully added.\n";
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Type the game title to remove: \n";
            cin.get();
            getline(cin, removeGame);
            gameInter = find(list.begin(), list.end(), removeGame);
            if (*gameInter == removeGame) {
                cout << "Title " << removeGame << " found\n";
                list.erase(gameInter);
                cout << "Title " << removeGame << " has been removed!\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Title " << removeGame << " cannot be found!\n";
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "\nYour Favorite Games Are: \n";

                for (gameInter = list.begin(); gameInter != list.end(); gameInter++) {
                    cout << listNum << ". " << *gameInter << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Thank You for your input! Goodbye\n";
            //userSelection = 4;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "That is not a valid option\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: 1) And this is why one should not use `using namespace std` in global scope: `vector<string> list;`. I.e. don't name your variables same as STL types. 2) What are the errors you encounter?

Comment: Down-voters: please comment!

Comment: As per comment #1, and "Failed attempt" - _what_ failed? You can't just say 'It's not working' and expect a solution with no description of the problem. The popularity of that approach never ceases to amaze me: how do people expect it to work? Anyway, you should probably just spare yourself the hassle of reinventing wheels manually when the stdlib provides fantastic features for cases precisely like this, such as an `std::set< std::pair<unsigned, std::string> >`, which will automatically order according to the rank in `pair::first` (and, if any ties exist, then the name in `pair::second`).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just started programming with C++ two weeks ago. Can you please provide an example that I can follow. Thanks again.

Comment: @Torbjörn I'm not receiving any error messages. The output is just not what I expected. for example attempt 1 nested for loop outputs  Your Favorite Games Are:
1. Contra
2. Contra
1. Mario
2. Mario
1. Zelda
2. Zelda

Comment: @user3574939 Change `cout << listNum << ". " << *gameInter << endl;` to `cout << listNum++ << ". " << *gameInter << endl;` and add `listNum = 1;` right before `for (gameInter = list.begin(); gameInter != list.end(); gameInter++) {`

Comment: @Torbjörn Why additional comments actually? The question misses a [MCVE] in 1st place. If you want to dissect what's shown, feel free to answer (an off topic question).

Comment: @DimChtz That worked! Thank You

Comment: @Torbjörn Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using specialised containers provided by the standard library to make your life easier. They exist to avoid you having to painstakingly reinvent the wheel, so that you can focus on what you need to do, not the boring details and scaffolding around it! Don't get me wrong: using `vector` puts you ahead of many - by not manually allocating your own array - but we can do better.

For example, to create a group of games, with ranks and titles, which will be automatically sorted by their ranks (and if a tie occurs, their titles):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>  // pair

// Represent a game by its rank and title (typedef)
using game_type = std::pair<unsigned, std::string>;

// Create an ordered set of games
std::set<game_type> games;
// Populate it. You could do this from standard input.
games.emplace(3, "GTA V"); // constructs element in-place
games.emplace(1, "Legend Of Zelda");
games.emplace(2, "Contra");

// Verify that std::pair sorts by .first (and then .second)
for (auto const &it: games) { // tidy C++11 iteration syntax
    std::cout << it.first << ": " << it.second << std::endl;
}
```

The output is what you want:

> ```
> 1: Legend of Zelda
> 2: Contra
> 3: GTA V
> ```

Want to populate the `map` from user input instead? Sure. Just grab the rank and title into temporary variables, then `emplace(theRank, theTitle)`.

You can then start to think about how to erase based on rank and quite quickly find the answer in `std::set`'s documentation or `<algorithm>`. I see you've already looked at the latter already. That's great! It's there to help us out but sometimes gets overlooked. Or people use its functions but don't `#include` it and rely on indirect inclusion elsewhere...

Anyway. Maybe now you want/need ranks to be unique, and need to catch situations where the user enters a duplicate? Then check out `std::map`.

And so on. There are so many great possibilities in the standard library. It would be a shame for you to miss out on those while also getting headaches from unknowingly trying to reinvent them yourself. ;-)